# JPA 2.2 `EntityManager.merge` inserting instead of updating

Tags: eclipselink, websphere-liberty, jpa-2.1, open-liberty

I have only this simple Entity (no relationships at all, just some scalar fields):

```
@Entity
@Table
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @Column
  private String myPK;

  /* ...other fields... */

  public MyEntity(String myPK /* ... other fields ... */) {
    this.myPK = myPK;
    /* ... */
  }

  /* getters and setters and toString and hashcode et al. */
}
```

Then at the start of a test run I do this (inside arquillian, but it doesn't really matter):

```
EntityManager manager;
/* ... manager is injected actually ... */
manager.merge(new MyEntity("0" /* ... */));
```

It works. That is, the table line whose PK is `"0"` got updated with the remaining fields, so the test has a stable starting point.

Now I've changed the `myPK` field to be `Long` instead of `String`. Yes, only this change (and the `new MyEntity(0L /* ... */)`).

It doesn't work anymore.

The `merge` actually tries to insert a new row, where the previous one already exists. Then the database refused to insert a duplicate PK.

Why does it UPDATE the row when using `String` as PK, but then it INSERTS when using `Long` as PK?

I'm using OpenLiberty 21.0.0.4 (wlp-1.0.51.cl210420210407-0944).

It uses EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4.

On transaction commit it spills:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (XPK) violate

 Error Code: 1
 Call: INSERT INTO MyEntity (myPK, ...) VALUES (?, ...)
     bind => [0, ...]
 Query: InsertObjectQuery(MyEntity(myPK=0, ...))
     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:908)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:970)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:640)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:567)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2099)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:313)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:277)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:263)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:413)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:167)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:182)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:504)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:82)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:92)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:316)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:60)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:810)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:110)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:87)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2983)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1830)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:229)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:141)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4398)
```

Comment: I've just found that the problem happes exclusively with `myPK=0`. Other values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) for the primary key are working fine.

Comment: After enabling eclipselink tracing, I can see a that for `myPK=1`  (or anything not `0`), it first `SELECTs` the entity, then `UPDATEs` the mismatching fields. For `myPK=0` it just `INSERTs`.

Comment: Alright, I've just learned about the `eclipselink.allow-zero-id` property.

Comment: Since it is a test, I'll just change the `0` id to something else.

Comment: **Now I've changed the myPK field to be Long instead of String**

Are you rebuilding the entity table as well? I would assume the original table had the primary key as a VARCHAR (depending on the DB platform) and you have now changed the entity mapping to a new type. The table SHOULD also be altered or regenerated, otherwise the persistence provider has no way of knowing the table doesn't match the entity mappings. There may be some weird conversion behavior or failing queries without updating the database